# How to subset spark dataframe by prefixes of the column names?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, prefixes

The column names of my spark dataframe *df* are: A_x1, A_x2, B_x1, B_x2, C_x1, C_x2.

How do I create 3 new spark dataframes from *df* by using the prefixes? The output should look like this:

- dataframe named *A_* contains the columns A_x1, A_x2,
- dataframe named *B_* contains the columns B_x1, B_x2,
- dataframe named *C_* contains the columns C_x1, C_x2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `colRegex` to filter the columns:

```
A_ = df.select(df.colRegex('`A_.*`'))
B_ = df.select(df.colRegex('`B_.*`'))
C_ = df.select(df.colRegex('`C_.*`'))
```